# ASP.Net webforms: how to cancel a pending update to input controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using c#/Asp.Net webforms to collect data in a long form.

I'm using standard Asp.Net validation controls/techniques.

The form is split into several parts (wizard style). The user completes one section before being allowed to go onto the next section.

Each completed section has an Edit button, so the user can go back at any point and make changes to a previous section's data.

Currently there is only a 'continue' button available in edit mode, When the user chooses edit, make changes, then clicks 'continue', the data is re-validated and the user returned to the original position if successful.

However, this does not cover all scenarios. Suppose the user updates a textbox or dropdown option then decides to revert back to the original data.

At present they would need to manually reset the data back to the original state before clicking continue. Not ideal.

The answer would be to introduce a cancel button. The button event should ignore any changes to the data and simply return back to the original position.

However, I'm unsure how this would work given a postback would occur when the cancel button was clicked. I'm using update panels, but this shouldn't make a difference to the solution.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a Microsoft sample page or offer advice, it would be appreciated.

For the moment, I'm stumped.

Comment: are you intending to cancel just one section of the wizard, or the whole form? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: Only, a section. Suppose the user has previously selected a value of '500' for some textbox. They go back and change the value to 600,but subsequently decide not to proceed with the change. Clicking the cancel button should leave the data 'as was', regardless of whether its has changed or not.

Comment: So I guess it could just refresh the page (or update panel) to re-load that section with the default / previous saved state of the fields (as appropriate), without performing any kind of save operation? Basically the same behaviour as when the section was loaded by coming from the previous section, I'd have thought.

Comment: The page still has to do something. It has to return back to the previous section, which means changing visibility - hide the current section and show the next section (where the user originally arrived from), so a simple refresh doesn't seem like it will be sufficient.

Comment: So do that navigation then, and next time the user decides to come back to the "cancelled" section, won't it re-fetch the last saved data from the server for that section, and populate the section? Or is the problem that navigation automatically includes saving the current section? If so you'd have to have a special case for the Cancel button where it navigates without saving. Without seeing / understanding precisely how you've designed it, it's hard to give a more exact suggestion.

Comment: The bit I'm not certain about is this. The user presses the edit button - section 2 is closed and section reopened. The user changes the value of a textbox but then presses cancel. The cancel process works in reverse, so secion 2 reopens and section 1 recloses. Won't the changes made be preseved due to the postback?

Comment: I don't know, it depends what your code does when you post back. If you clicked a different button, a different event will run, so you can do something different if you want to.

Comment: It can be a totally different event a far as I'm concerned but won't the textbox value be automatically overwritten on postback regardless of what I do in the event?

Comment: I don't know, it depends what your code does. And in the event, you can do whatever you like to change the default behaviour, if needed. I'm struggling to see what the difficulty is. If you're not sure, you can always make a prototype.

Comment: Sorry - my fault - I don't think I'm explaining myself well enough. Suppose I have a submit button wired up to an event. Submit is clicked - I call a validation event - if all is okay the page is updated. In the case of a cancel button, an event is still called (albeit with no validation) but surely the page will still be updated and any changes made to input data carried forward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164184/discussion-between-adyson-and-john-ohara).